# I hosted my website on Azure Linux VM but I can’t access the website with the designated ip on chrome it doesn’t not respond

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm hosting my website on an Azure Linux VM, but I can't access it using the ip given. I have tried  adding inbound rules, but there was no result. I also tried allowing the VM to listen to the particular ports 80 and 83 and added an inbound rule - no result still.
I tried redeploying, but no changes. I tried reapplying, but still no results. I still can't access it through the IP on Chrome.

I am still new to azure VMs as I am only used to aws ec2. I don't know what else to do to resolve this.
Most of the solutions I see here are for window VMs.

Comment: Did you check the NSG rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, Check the firewall settings on the VM itself it allows inbound traffic on the ports on your website.

Added NSG port like below:

[image]

Check the status of the web server (Apache or Nginx) running on the VM and make sure that it is listening on the correct ports.

```c
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw allow 80
sudo ufw allow 443
```

```c
sudo systemctl status apache2
or
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

```c
sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-12-28 05:50:49 UTC; 31min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 3756 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 4080)
     Memory: 10.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─3756 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─3759 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─3760 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Dec 28 05:50:48 vm1linux1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 28 05:50:49 vm1linux1 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

[image]

Still if the web server is not running, start it by running below command:

```c
sudo systemctl start apache2
or
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Now I am hosting my website on an Azure Linux VM check the below:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y apache2
```

***Output***:

```c
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjansson4
  liblua5.2-0 ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom www-browser openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  libjansson4 liblua5.2-0 ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1872 kB of archives
...................................
..................................
```

[image]

Now you can create new file:

```
cd /var/www/html
ls
vi index.html
sudo vi test.html
```

In file you can add your own `sudo vi test.html` ,  for sample I added below html code.

```
<html>
    
    <h1> This is my website</h1>

</html>
```

change the name file:

```
#To save and change the file use below:
sudo mv index.html back.html
sudo mv test.html back.html
```

[image]

[image]